# How to select an option of a slim select with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, slimselect

I have some concatenated selects that work fine. By the way, I would like to convert those selects into slim selects but I found some difficulties in doing that.
For example, I have a select with ID `level_incarico`.
When I select an option of `level_incarico` greater than zero other selects should appear.
After that, when I change an option of a concatenated select for example in `select_nazione`, the option change correctly.
But when I select another time the option zero in `level_incarico` and the I select another time an option greater than zero in `level_incarico` appears another time the select `select_nazione` with the option already selected previously.

This is my javascript code:

```
$("#level_incarico").change(function(){
    var option_selected = $('option:selected', this).attr('value');
    document.getElementById('level_incarico_selected').value = option_selected;

    if (option_selected > 0) {
        $('.nazione').css('display','block');
        $('.regione').css('display','none');
        $('.provincie').css('display','none');
        $('.comune').css('display','none');
        $('.altro_nazione').css('display','none');
        $("#select_regione").val(0);
        $("#select_provincia").val(0);
        $("#select_comune").val(0);
        $("#select_nazione").val(0);
        $("#altro_input_nazioni").val("");
    } else {
        $('.nazione').css('display','none');
        $('.regione').css('display','none');
        $('.provincie').css('display','none');
        $('.comune').css('display','none');
        $('.altro_nazione').css('display','none');
        $("#select_nazione").val(0); //here
        $("#select_regione").val(0);
        $("#select_provincia").val(0);
        $("#select_comune").val(0);
        $("#altro_input_nazioni").val("");
    }
});
```

This is how I create the selects:

```
new SlimSelect({
    select: '#select_nazione'
})

new SlimSelect({
    select: '#level_incarico'
})
```

In other words, the reset of the selected options `$("#select_nazione").val(0);` does not work correctly. It works with normal selects, but not with slim select.

Here how I fill in `level_incarico`:

```
        echo "<select id='level_incarico' name='level_incarico'>";
        echo "<option></option>";
        echo "<option value='0' " . (($ra_level == 0 && $id > 0)  ? 'selected' : '') . " >Mondiale</option>";
        echo "<option value='1' " . (($ra_level == 1 && $id > 0)  ? 'selected' : '') . " >Nazionale</option>";
        echo "<option value='2' " . (($ra_level == 2 && $id > 0)  ? 'selected' : '') . " >Regionale</option>";
        echo "<option value='3' " . (($ra_level == 3 && $id > 0)  ? 'selected' : '') . " >Provinciale</option>";
        echo "<option value='4' " . (($ra_level == 4 && $id > 0)  ? 'selected' : '') . " >Comunale</option>";
        echo "</select>";
```

Here how I fill in `select_nazione`:

```
    echo "<select id='select_nazione' name='select_nazione' required>";

    echo "<option value='0'>Seleziona...</option>";
    
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
                $nazione_id_val=intval($row['country_id']);
                $nazione_nome_val=$row['country_name'];
                
                if($ra_level > 0) {
                    if ($nazione_id_val == $id_nazione) 
                        {
                            $selected = "selected" ;
                        } else {
                            $selected = "" ;
                        }   
                    
                }
                echo"<option value='$nazione_id_val' $selected>$nazione_nome_val</option>";
            }
    echo "</select>";
```

Can help?

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] instead of a bunch of little pieces of code. The question is not related to PHP, so please post RENDERED HTML and script only

Comment: As above, if you're asking a question about html/javascript/jquery then please provide the *rendered* html - how you generate it server-side is not relevant for a javascript/jquery question (as noted in the updated comment above :) )

Comment: Also recommended to stay DRY:  `$('.nazione').toggle(this.value>0)`

Comment: Can you provide information regarding "slimselect"?   The SO wiki on this is empty.  At the least what's the url for the .js

Comment: @freedomn-m He should [include it in the snippet](https://www.google.com/search?q=SlimSelect+cdn)

Comment: Also please  [RTM](http://slimselectjs.com/methods): `select.set('value')`

Comment: @freedomn-m I could not help myself answering

Comment: @mplungjan I started an answer, but couldn't be bothered to add the basic code from the manual or create a snippet when OP hadn't, so deleted it as it was a link-only answer :)  I would have had to downvote my own answer - lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Why do you have an else for the values that are all 0
- Why do you have display none in both branches?

Would this help you? I got the code from the [manual](http://slimselectjs.com/methods)

```js
const $slimNazione  = new SlimSelect({
   select: '#select_nazione',
   onChange: (info) => {
    console.log(info.value)
  }
})

const $slimIncario = new SlimSelect({
  select: '#level_incarico',
  onChange: (info) => {
    console.log(info.value)
    const val = +info.value;
    $('.nazione').toggle(val > 0);
    $('.regione').hide();
    $('.provincie').hide();
    $('.comune').hide();
    $('.altro_nazione').hide();
    $slimNazione.set('0')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.27.0/slimselect.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slim-select/1.27.0/slimselect.css"/>

<select id='select_nazione' name='select_nazione'>
  <option value="0">Seleziona...</option>
  <option value='A'>A</option>
  <option value='B'>B</option>
  <option value='C'>C</option>
</select>

<select id='level_incarico' name='level_incarico'>
  <option></option>
  <option value='0'>Mondiale</option>
  <option value='1'>Nazionale</option>
  <option value='2'>Regionale</option>
  <option value='3'>Provinciale</option>
  <option value='4'>Comunale</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

slim-select is built without jQuery...on purpose.  If you have jQuery (and plan on keeping it in your stack), I would recommend using select2 instead.  slim-select is a great library and has a smaller foot print due to not being dependent on jQuery.  But, select2...dare I say...is better.  Or, at least has more convenience features.  I found select2 easier to use, but my desire to cut out jQuery led me to adopt slim-select.